# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and "Exported receiver does not require permission"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-broadcast

My question is not a duplicate: I have searched SO and on the web and haven't found a definite answer yet.

In a bluetooth-related app I would like a background `Service` to be started on device boot and then connect to a bluetooth beacon (if available) and post Android notifications to the user on certain events.

So I have added following lines to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <service 
        android:name="ScanService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

However Eclipse displays the warning **Exported receiver does not require permission** which probably means, that any app could run my service. And of course I don't want that.

I want only the Android OS (at the boot time) and my MainActivity (acting as settings GUI-frontend to the background service) being able to do (re)start the ScanService.

There are 2 common suggestions for this problem:

1. First is to add [android:exported="false"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) to the intent filter.
2. Second is to add [android:permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) to the intent filter.

But I still have follow-up questions please:

1. Will `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast still be delivered to the "non-exported" service?
2. What permission to specify here, is it really `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE` or something else (and does Android-system needs this permission?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** `BOOT_COMPLETED` is an *inter-app*, system-wide broadcast sent by the OS, and will indeed be heard by all app components that filter this broadcast. *Not exported* merely means that **other apps** cannot make use of that component; the broadcast action will certainly be heard by the receiver.

**2.** `BOOT_COMPLETED` is very much the broadcast you need to use here. Set `android:exported="false"` and add that permission in the manifest.

**EDIT:**

`BOOT_COMPLETED` is a *broadcast action*. To intercept it on boot,  you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver`, and there you can start the `Service`. In your manifest, add

```
<receiver 

    android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

And create the class

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, ScanService.class);
        context.startService(i);

    }
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Will **my app** (the MainActivity) still be able to run the "not exported" ScanService?

Comment: Yes, certainly, the `exported` tag is used to indicate whether an app component can or cannot be used by *other* apps.

Comment: Not yet, because I don't know how to log messages for later inspection from my service... Currently I only see log messages when I connect the device to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to bear in mind if:
**Android receiver & RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED & BOOT_COMPLETED failure to start your service**

After the obvious stuff:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
and:
            <receiver 
                   android:name="com.twiggwidgets.service.MyScheduleReceiver"
                   android:enabled="true"
                   android:exported="true"
            >
                <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

***Still pulling your hair out ?***

**After Android 3.1**
" the system adds **FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES** to all broadcast intents."
This means you, after 3.1, all apps are stopped on boot.
Why ?. For security reasons.

There are **RULES** to turn the flag off "FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES" .

(1) Your app needs to needs in phone storage, NOT sdcard otherwise the flag set.
 BOOT_COMPLETE is sent before external storage is mounted. if app is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message.

(2) If the user presses "Force close" from settings OR "unresponsive app" button, the flag is set.

(3) **If the application has never been run, the flag is set (never is relative to current boot state ;O) NEVER means in THIS boot OR you invalidated the flag in the last boot state)**.

Your Reciver will run on boot up (flag not set), if you follow the rules.

**info**

You can register you receiver your in code (it won't help for boot-up).

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.twiggwidgets.service.MyScheduleReceiver");

    MyScheduleReceiver myReceiver = new MyScheduleReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

//receiver's (are supposed to) run momentarily, but you knew that.
```

**Tip for testing**

```
Open console/terminal and navigating to /platform-tools (it should be in your path ;O)).
Type adb shell or on linux/mac ./adb shell
In the shell type "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

see android link :
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: booting is a NIGHTMARE, also check for exclusions in boot manager etc...<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> is just such a device specific example